# Instagrapi: tag users (not mention) and save as a draft

Tags: python, instagram, instagrapi

I would like to post in instagram using instagrapi. I've been able to, but I'm missing how to do the following:

- Tagging users on the screen, not only mentioning
- Saving the post as a draft instead of publishing

Any help? Or maybe I should look for another library?

Thank you